# Conditional operator is giving compilation error in c

Tags: c, compiler-errors, return, expression, conditional-operator

`(a>b) ? return a : return b;`

This code is giving compilation error why

Comment: Because "ternary operator" is supposed to produce a value. You can do `return (a>b)? a : b;` though

Comment: Or you can use an `if` / `else` *statement*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about material covered in an elementary C course that should be resolved by reading course materials and working on course assignments rather than by asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The syntax of the ternary operator is *e1* `?` *e2* `:` *e3*, where *e1*, *e2*, and *e3* are all *expressions*.  But `return` is a *statement*, and statements are "bigger than" expressions.

Comment: Basically it's for the same reason you can't say `if(return a)` or `int x = return a;`.

Comment: `?:` is not a drop-in replacement for `if`/`else`.  If you want to do one statement, or the other, you need a true `if`/`else` statement to do it.

Comment: Then why it works for (a>b) ? printf("a") : printf("b");

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator is defined the following way

```
logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

That is it consists from three expressions.

However instead of the second and the third expressions

```
(a>b) ? return a : return b;
```

you placed the statement `return`. So the compiler issues an error.

Instead you need to write a return statement with an expression containing the conditional operator like

```
return (a>b) ? a : b;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

`return (a>b) ? a : b;`

Answer (score 0):

`return a` doesn't evaluate to a value, which is an obvious requirement of the conditional operator's operands. How can the whole evaluate to a value if its operands don't evaluate to a value?

In more technical terms, operands must be expressions. `return a;` would be a valid statement, but `return a` isn't a valid expression because it doesn't evaluate to a value. This isn't specific to the conditional operator (`?:`). For example, `x + return y` and `x && return y` are just as invalid (in C).

You could use

```c
return a>b ? a : b;
```